# How to wait for document to load in Saucelab selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I'm experimenting with Saucelab atm and it is an amazing tool. I want to configure my code to wait for document and jquery to load so I can successfully take full screenshot of the page that I wish to test. I have added my script to JS Fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/ttLLdcq1/ and copy and pasted script:

```
"use strict";
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); // muse use selenium-webdriver version <=2.47.0
var username = "my_username";
var accessKey = "my_access_key";
var driver;
var deviceTypes = {
    desktop: 'desktop',
    mobile: 'mobile'
}
/*Desktops*/
var screenResolutions = {
    desktop: "1280x1024",
    tablet: "1024x768",
    mobile: "800x600"
};
var browsers = [
    /*Desktop*/
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'chrome',
        platform: 'Windows XP',
        version: '43.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.desktop
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'firefox',
        platform: 'Windows XP',
        version: '38.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.desktop
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'internet explorer',
        platform: 'Windows 10',
        version: '11.103',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.desktop
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'safari',
        platform: 'OS X 10.8',
        version: '6.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.desktop
    },
    /*Tablet*/
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'chrome',
        platform: 'Windows XP',
        version: '43.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.tablet
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'firefox',
        platform: 'Windows XP',
        version: '38.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.tablet
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'internet explorer',
        platform: 'Windows 10',
        version: '11.103',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.tablet
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.desktop,
        browser: 'safari',
        platform: 'OS X 10.8',
        version: '6.0',
        screenResolution: screenResolutions.tablet
    },
    /*Mobiles - Android*/
    {
        type: deviceTypes.mobile,
        browserName: 'android',
        platform: 'linux',
        version: '5.1',
        deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait'
    },

    {
        type: deviceTypes.mobile,
        browserName: 'android',
        platform: 'linux',
        version: '4.4',
        deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy S4 Emulator',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait'
    },
    {
        type: deviceTypes.mobile,
        browserName: 'iphone',
        platform: 'OS X 10.10',
        version: '9.2',
        deviceName: 'iPhone 5s',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait'
    }

];

var index = 0;

loopBrowsers();
function loopBrowsers(){

    var browserConfig = browsers[index];
    var capabilities;

    if(browserConfig.type === deviceTypes.desktop){
        capabilities = {
            'browserName': browserConfig.browser,
            'platform': browserConfig.platform,
            'version': browserConfig.version,
            'screenResolution': browserConfig.screenResolution,
            'username': username,
            'accessKey': accessKey
        }
    } else if (browserConfig.type === deviceTypes.mobile) {
        capabilities = {
            'browserName': browserConfig.browserName,
            'platform': browserConfig.platform,
            'version': browserConfig.version,
            'deviceName': browserConfig.deviceName,
            'deviceOrientation': browserConfig.deviceOrientation,
            'username': username,
            'accessKey': accessKey
        }
    }

    driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(capabilities).
    usingServer("http://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub").
    build();

    driver.get('http://example.com');

    //Taking screenshot on currently targeting browser
    driver.takeScreenshot().then(
        function(image, err){

            var fileName;

            if(browserConfig.type === deviceTypes.desktop){
                fileName = "screen_"+browserConfig.browser+"_"+browserConfig.screenResolution;
            } else if (browserConfig.type === deviceTypes.mobile) {
                fileName = "screen_"+browserConfig.deviceName+"_"+browserConfig.deviceOrientation;
            }

            require('fs').writeFile("screenshots/"+ fileName +".png", image, 'base64', function(err){
                console.log("Completed screenshot: " + index + " any errors: " + err);

                index++;
                if(index < browsers.length){
                    loopBrowsers();
                } else {

                }
            });
        }
    );
    driver.quit();
}
```

Basically, I want to wait for document to load, then take a screenshot. Moreover, is there any comprehensive tutorial of using JS with Selenium? For example, I want to select an element and see if that element is located in correct position and etc. Is there any wrapper framework that does this and work with Saucelab? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out you can just wait for last elements to load, which pretty much means page is loaded.